# specific custom path of firefox for executing the automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, geckodriver, robotframework-browser

I am using "SeleniumLibrary"  in robot framework . I installed two version of firefox in my machine . I would like to use the specific custom path of firefox for executing the automation .Please help me out to sort out this issue as earlier as possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Create webdriver](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Create%20Webdriver) keyword with options like that:

```
Create webdriver   Firefox     firefox_binary=C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox2\\firefox.exe    executable_path=C:\\opt\\webdrivers2\\geckodriver.exe
```

Tested on:

- robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0
- selenium==4.1.5